# Typescript - Bind ngModel to property of object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, undefined, ngmodel

I have an object called `user`:

```
let user = {};
```

How can I bind an input to a undefined property? E.g.

```
<input [(ngModel)]="user.name" placeholder="Enter your name"></input>
```

And whenever the user enters his name, I want the `ngModel` to create the undefined property of that object and result in this:

```
user = {name: "John"};
```

Is this also possible to be done at deepter levels? E.g.

```
<input [(ngModel)]="user.homeaddress.postcode" placeholder="Enter your post code"></input>
```

to result in:

```
user = {name: "John", homeaddress: {postcode: "E20 1QS"}};
```

Answer (score 3):

Two way data binding supports any nested objects, you just need to use it as,

```
<input [(ngModel)]="user.homeaddress.postcode" placeholder="Enter your post code"></input>
```

since you have initialized data it wont throw any error.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this also possible to be done at deepter levels?

Yes. `"user.homeaddress.postcode"` will work.